# Adding USB capabilities to an OS

Tags: c, operating-system, usb

I'm working on an OS (new kernel, nonlinux), and I was wondering how I would go about adding USB functionality. I'm not even sure what I should be working on, should I start with an EHCI interface for USB 2.0? Am I able to just start writing drivers without worrying about a host controller interface?

Any opinions are welcome, I'm new to the project so I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: Even though you're in non-Linux land you would probably get some use out of exploring the usb stack in the Linux kernel. If you truly have full control you can do whatever you want, but *something* has to talk directly to the hardware and something has to implement the USB protocol - how you do that depends on what you are truly trying to accomplish.

Comment: I just need to get basic USB functionality. USB1.1 low speed is all I really need at the moment.

Would you suggest looking at the USB1.1 spec sheet here: http://mprolab.teipir.gr/vivlio80X86/usb11.pdf

Or should I just look at how Linux does it?

Comment: Both - the specs are boring, but have the right info; [usb.org](http://www.usb.org/home) will have all the technical information you should need. But looking at the Linux sources will give you a better understanding on how your stuff will need to be designed and how you actually access the hardware from the host. This may be a bit higher level, but [USB Complete](http://www.amazon.com/USB-Complete-Developers-Guide-Guides/dp/1931448086) is my favorite USB book. I wish I had a better answer for you but I've only worked on USB function drivers above where you are starting. Good luck!